# Insert of a new node into a binary tree and return its head pointer

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

Hello i need to make a function that inserts a new node into a binary search tree and returns a pointer to the head/root of that tree.
My problem is with the returned value, i cant seem to figure out how to return the head of the tree in a recursive way as seen below.

```
tree_type insertNode (tree_type tree, int data) {

    tree_type temp = NULL;

    if(!tree)
    {
        temp = (tree_type)malloc(3*sizeof(tree_type)); 

        temp->left = temp->right = NULL;

        temp->data = data;

        tree = temp;

        return ;
    }

    if(data < tree->data)
    {
        insertNode(tree->left, data);
    }
    else if(data > tree->data)
    {
       insertNode(tree->right, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please align your code properly before posting

Comment: `(tree_type)malloc(3*sizeof(tree_type)); ` Huh?

Comment: There is something really wrong with the way you do `malloc`. Please show the definition of `tree_type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the assignment `tree = temp` is useless, because `tree` is a local variable which disappears when the function returns.

Secondly, a `return;` in a function which is declared as returning a type other than `void` requires a diagnostic; it is not valid C or C++.

Instead of

```
tree = temp;
return;
```

consider returning the new tree:

```
return temp;
```

(There is no need for the variable `temp`; you could just use the variable `tree` in that case and then `return tree`).

The problem of how to return the root node is simple:

```
if(data < tree->data)
{
    tree->left = insertNode(tree->left, data);
    return tree;
}
```

and so forth. If you eliminate the variable `temp` and use `tree` in the `malloc` case, your function can just have a single return point which consists of `return tree;`.

If `tree->left` is null, then `insertNode(tree->left, data)` receives a null left argument and so receives a new node. We must capture this return value and assign it to `tree->left`.  If `tree->left` is not null, then `insertNode` will just return `tree->left` and so the assignment just writes the same value back into `tree->left`.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you need?

```
if(!tree)
{
    temp = (tree_type) malloc(sizeof(*temp)); 
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
    temp->data = data;

    return temp;
}

if(data < tree->data)
{
    tree->left = insertNode(tree->left, data);
    return tree->left;
}
else if(data > tree->data)
{
    tree->right = insertNode(tree->right, data);
    return tree->right;
}
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thanks, I've missed it during copy-pasting OP's code.